# Add properties file for custom plugin in Nutch

Tags: java, ant, properties, web-scraping, nutch

I'm a beginner in Nutch. I have done crawling, created a custom plugin based on different tutorials. For a particular task, my Java class have to use a properties file named `sample.properties` for some tasks. I've getting a **NullPointerException** on the following code.

```
Properties property = new Properties();
        InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties");
        property.load(input);
```

I don't know where to place this properties file, because it doesn't moves  to the compiled jar after compiling with ant. Currently I'm placing at the same directory of java class. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it must be in the resources folder

Comment: I have added there too. But after compiling using ant, it doesn't there in the plugin.jar and I am getting that Exception.

Comment: you should have an ant target that is building your jar (using 'jar' ant task). I think that you have to explicitly include your resources using a fileset in that jar task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved by adding a copy task in plugin's `build.xml` as :

```
<copy todir="${build.classes}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties"/>
</copy>
```

It copies the properties file to the compiled jar and issue was solved. Cheers !!

EDIT :

I just used another method also. Moved the properties file to conf directory and get the input in Parsefilter by,

```
Properties property = new Properties();
InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("sample.properties");
property.load(input);
```